# SharePoint navigation link to user's OneDrive

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, office-365

I am a WordPress user and new to SharePoint. I am trying to add a main navigation link to users personal drive in a SP site. I know that OneDrive url goes like this:

```
https://XYZ-my.sharepoint.com/personal/<USRNME>_<DOMAIN>/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx.
```

If some one can help me how to make the above url dynamic? So that users clicking the above link are directed to their personal onedrive automatically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I guess you can redirect users to the generic URL (https://XYZ-my.sharepoint.com/) Which will automatically redirect to one's own personal one drive.